# Writing an infinite sum (of a function that has an integral) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum, infinite

I am required to show that:

[image: Sum from i=1 to infinity of the square of the absolute value of c sub i equals 1]

The annoying thing is that c_i is equal to the integral of the function G. Here is my attempt.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def G(x,n):
    P = (np.sqrt(735))*(np.sqrt(2))*np.sin(n*np.pi*x)*((x**3.0) - (11.0/7.0)*(x**2.0) + (4.0/7.0)*(x))
    return P

def Sum(x, n):
    i = 1
    S = 0
    I, err = quad(G, 0, 1, args=(i))
    while (i<n):
        S = S + I
        i = i + 1
    return S
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 250)    
print Sum(x, 200)
```

The problem I am having is writing the summation part. When I run this I get a bigger number the more values I give it. **If n is chosen to be quite high (instead of infinity) it can be shown how the sum tends to 1**

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok it's clear now that you mention it.

Comment: You're not squaring the integral before adding it to `S`.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I squared it and the same problem occurs. However answers are now not quite as big as before.

Comment: Unclear to me whether `args=(i)` matters.  That's exactly the same as `args=i`.  If you intended to pass a tuple with one element, then `args=(i,)` is the way to do it.  Overall, the most _likely_ cause is that there's an error in the coding of `G` - but we can't check that for you.

Comment: Hmm, I will double-check that. So you're saying the code for the summation should technically work? I'm a little rusty with while loops so I thought the problem might be there.

Comment: The integral of the function G, over what range?

Comment: The range is between 0 and 1

Comment: The function G, can you put it in its most general form that you need, (but with the TeX plugin you used already). Just to know if you cant just analytically calculate the integral. If you need to really prove it, you should maybe go to http://math.stackexchange.com ? (If you prove something in maths for the first 100000 numbers, you cant say what it will give for bigger numbers, you have to epsilon-delta-style prove it?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem has much pedagogic value.

As @alko points out, this problem can be solved analytically.  If the intention is to prove that the sum is equal to one then it *should* be done analytically.

Perhaps, this is just a simpler version of something that needs to be done and the actual problem is not solvable analytically.  In that case, solving a simpler problem such as this one is a good first step.  Unfortunately, whenever we solve something numerically we introduce new sets of problems.

Let us proceed as suggested in the question and the correction given by @alko.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integ

def g(x) :
    return np.sqrt(1470) * (x**3-11./7*x**2+4./7*x)

def G(x,n) :
    return np.sin(n*np.pi*x) * g(x)

def do_integral (N) :
    res = np.zeros(N)
    err = np.zeros(N)
    for n in xrange(1,N) :
        (res[n],err[n]) = integ.quad(G, 0, 1, args=(n,))
    return (res,err)

(c,err) = do_integral(500)
S = np.cumsum(c[1:]**2) # skip n=0
```

(The reason why I define two "G" functions will be apparent below.)

Once run the array `S` will contain the desired sum as a function of n.  It should be one.  Now, when we run this within ipython it will be somewhat slow and the first time we will get some long warning message, but the code will seem to run.  Further, if we run it again (in the same ipython session) we will not get a warning message so we can just ignore that, right? **Wrong** but we will ignore it anyway since it is common to do so.

If we look at `S` it seems to be showing what we want until about `S[200]` where things start to go wrong, the value starts to grow!  What is wrong with the computer?!  Nothing, and we ignored another indicator of a problem.  `quad()` returns an error estimate along with an estimate of the integral.  We typically ignore the error estimate but shouldn't.  If we plot the S and error values we find the following.
[image: Integration of G function]

So we see that yes, the value of S goes horribly wrong, but `quad()` was also telling us this would happen!  In fact, the warning we ignored also told us the same thing.

How do we understand this and fix it?  At this point I will stop with the story telling.  If staring at the `G(x,n)` doesn't make it clear then it would be good to plot that function for a large `n` over the range of integration.  We will find it is a wildly oscillating function so it isn't surprising that it is hard to integrate numerically.  There must be a better way.

Of course there is a better way.  If we look at the documentation for `quad()` and run `quad_explain()` we can learn about weight functions.  The sine is a common weight function that appears in integrals so there are special techniques for handling this case.  Thus, a better approach is as follows (now we see why I defined `g(x)`:

```
def do_integral_weighted (N) :
    res = np.zeros(N)
    err = np.zeros(N)
    for n in xrange(1,N) :
        (res[n],err[n]) = integ.quad(g, 0, 1, weight='sin', wvar=n*np.pi)
    return (res,err)

(cw,errw) = do_integral_weighted(500)
Sw = np.cumsum(cw[1:]**2) # skip n=0
```

This we find runs much faster and is much more accurate as shown in the plot
[image: Integration of g function]
So we get a stable answer, no warnings printed, and a tiny integration error.

We learn a few things from working this problem

1. Problems that can be solved analytically should be solved analytically.
2. The numerical implementation of a mathematical expression is often not as straight forward as we may have hoped.
3. Do not ignore warnings and do not ignore the error information provided by the routines we are using.
4. Numerical techniques are different than analytic techniques.  numpy/scipy provide extremely powerful tools.  We need to explore these tools to fully exploit their power.

Answer (score 5):

You have errror in your summing. Move `quad` inside loop, and evaluate sum of squares  (instead of currently evaluated sum(c_i)) this way:

```
def Sum(x, n):
    S = 0
    for i in range(n):
        I, _err = quad(G, 0, 1, args=(i))
        S = S + I**2
    return S
```

By the way, how can you SHOW that limit of this sum equals 1? It can be only shown by some  math evaluations, not computations. You can just illustrate that.

Comment: It now gets much closer to 1 but after around n=400 it starts going above 1. And I guess showing it graphically is a good way.

Comment: The docs for `quad()` say `args=` should give a tuple. So, as noted in a comment before, that should be `args=(i,)` instead.  Quite possible it's working as-is by accident, though.  Note that for larger and larger `n`, the numeric `sin(n*np.pi*x)` is a worse and worse approximation.

Comment: @TimPeters , quad code starts with ``if not isinstance(args, tuple): args = (args,)``, so it is intended behaviour.